# Fix Insert proc

Tags: t-sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.com_project_transaction_link 
  WHERE pt_tr_transaction_id = @transactionId 
  AND pt_pj_project_id = @projectId)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.com_project_transaction_link(pt_tr_transaction_id, pt_pj_project_id) 
   VALUES (@transactionId, @projectId)
END
```

I want to fix this proc. Right now, if it DOESN'T find a record that has the passed in `projectId` AND `transactionId`, it will insert it. I want to make this so if it finds the `transactionId` at ALL, it will perform an update with the new `projectId`, however if it doesn't find it, it will do what it does now.

Can I grab some help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.com_project_transaction_link 
 WHERE pt_tr_transaction_id = @transactionId)
BEGIN
  UPDATE ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT...
END
```

Comment: check my update, its saying incorrent syntax near then and else?

Comment: You need to remove the `THEN` keyword